# ACL's on Sci Linux 6 ext4 not behaving like I think they should

Tags: redhat, access-control-list, ext4

I've got a fresh install of Scientific Linux 6, and am playing a bit with acls.  All filesystems are ext4.

In this particular case, I think have set up the acl's so that any user in the admin group has rwx access to /usr/src.

```
# setfacl -R -m d:g:admin:rwx /usr/src
# exit
exit

[~]$ getfacl /usr/src
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: usr/src
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:admin:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

However, logging out and back in:

```
[~]$ touch /usr/src/test
touch: cannot touch `/usr/src/test': Permission denied
```

This user is in the admin group:

```
[~]$ id
uid=500(xx) gid=500(xx)     groups=500(xx),997(admin) 
context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Now, I see that 'group' is `r-x`, but my understanding is that that only applies to the owning gid (500 in this case).

So what am I doing wrong, or otherwise missing, here?

Comment: You don't need to change the title of the question to reflect that it's been solved.  You can however, accept DerfK's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an SELinux context, so I wouldn't rule out SELinux blocking you from writing to `/usr/src` (check the audit.log for relevant messages).

However, for the ACL itself, the `default:` ACLs on a directory are used for objects you create in that directory, so `d:g:admin:rwx` means that things created in the directory would be writable by admin, not that the directory itself is writable by the admin group.  Try just `g:admin:rwx`